# Dual boot issue with Kubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10, partitioning

[Not installing on ext4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9omoI.png)

[The disk partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVXsW.png)

I'll be brief with what happened.
I had Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10 alongside with grub as my boot  manager. Everything seemed to work fine but Ubuntu had some internal errors occurring repetitively. So I decided to uninstall Ubuntu and install Kubuntu. Without any search on Google I deleted the Ubuntu partition from windows 10. When I rebooted my pc, grub rescue was shown. I prepared a windows 10 thumbdrive and used the advanced options in the Recovery options and typed bootrec.exe/fixmbr. Now when I prepared a bootable usb for Kubuntu to install the partitions have some issues. It doesn't show the option for install alongside windows. All the partitions are basic.

Comment: Can you still make the install on the previous partition you used for Ubuntu? I think that you should works fine.

Comment: The 140 GB partition is not visible on Kubuntu. I can post a pic if you want to have a look.

Comment: Boot from a live (k)ubuntu and see if you can fix it (or at least see it) with gparted. And post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` please

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70510475f408d69a10e0958993b0f235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh that's very clear now, you cannot install a Linux system on a NTFS partition, that's why you can't install Kubuntu since you only have NTFS partitions. I guess when you deleted the partition from Windows, it automatically formatted it to NTFS. All you need to do is to use Gparted from your live and format the partition in which you want to install Kubuntu to ext4:

- Open Gparted
- Select the partition for Kubuntu
- Right-click : format to -> ext4
- Apply operations ( Ctrl+Return)

Then try to install Kubuntu again and you should be good :)

Comment: Will my content from the drive be deleted totally?

Comment: Only the content from the partition you selected. Since you erased you previous Ubuntu partition not long ago, it should, be the one with very low used space, and you can recognize your partition from their sizes. If you are unsure, make an new ext4 partition on the 150GB of free space at the end of your disk.

Comment: I am unable to install on the 150 GB partition. It tells me to resize the NTFS partition.

Comment: Are you sure the 150GB partition is now an ext4 partition? Can you please tell me the size/number of partition you used for windows? That could allow me to offer you a better help.

Comment: I have 2 primary and 1 logical partition for windows and 1 primary partition for Kubuntu

Comment: i have uploaded an image in my question @Dark

Comment: Ok so format the partition to ext4 (if not alreay) for Kubuntu. Then during the install, at Disk Setup, choose Manual and select that partition to install Kubuntu on it. The only difference between the "Before" and "After" disk layout should be that Kubuntu is on that partition. Then proceed to install, if that doesn't work please post another screenshot of the installation menu.

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped :)